# How to get the absolute path relative to the project root without double slashes?

Tags: python, django

I defined this function to get the absolute path relative to the project root:

```
def relpath(*x):
    return os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', *x))

GET_PATH = (
    relpath('django/dir/'),  #tuple
)
```

The problem is that I get the path with double slashes (on Windows), like this:

```
C:\\\\Users\\\\Fuiba\\\\Desktop\\\\Apps\\\\django\\\\dir
```

Why do I get the path with 4 slashes?
Is there a way to avoid this behavior or I can remove the repeated slashed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In my django projects I'm using unipath. It is simplifying a lot
Try to use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unipath/1.0
It is really nice and self explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Although I was unable to repeat your problem, you can remove extra spaces, using the string method `replace`:

```
s = 'C:\\\\Users\\\\Fuiba\\\\Desktop\\\\Apps\\\\django\\\\dir'

print(s.replace('\\\\','\\')) #C:\Users\Fuiba\Desktop\Apps\django\dir
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear. I get the 4 slashed when I use tuple. (I edited my question) Thanks for answer. I tried with: 
`s = relpath('django/dir/')
GET_PATH = (
    s.replace('\\\\','\\'),
)` but doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can not repeat your problem: your code (without using `replace`) gives me two slashes, like this: `(C:\\Users\\Fuiba\\Desktop\\Apps\\django\\dir,)`